# iPhone : How to make transparent XIB from which we can see previous view's uitableview

Tags: uitableview, ios6, xib, ios7

I want to make transparent xib view from which we can see previous view's uitableview.

I have one view which contain uitableview (listView.xib), from its one of navigation item, we can open one popup view or we can say that one another view(filterView.xib).  I want to make this filterView.xib as transparent that we can see previous list of data - listView.xib.

```
its Works in IOS7 as well <= IOS7?
```

Comment: change Alpha value of view .

Comment: This question brushed into NDA based SDKs. The OP is not allowed to discuss iOS 7.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

do it same thing and set the color of the view to clear color and change the alpha value to .5

Comment: after doing this, filterView.xib's content (label, tableview) look like in light color. we can see Black color as gray color. How to fix it ?

Comment: Careful, you have to be sure to make the view that **contains* the custom xib, as well as the xib contents to **clear**